# Elasticsearch 2.0, Delete with Java Api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to make a delete request in Java Api (I use Scala, but it's the same) using a query range. 
I have installed a new plug-in delete-by-query but I don't understand how using a Java Api client to make a request with range query.

This is the range query that I need:

```
DELETE /myindex/mydata/_query
{
    "range" : {
        "expired" : {
            "lte": "now"
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you